# comparing filenames and displaying files with most word matches?

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to calculate the amount of matching words in filenames in order to determine if the files might even remotely be about the same subject. I know how to turn the filename into variables...

```
set count=0
for %%i in (%filename%) do set "word%count%=%%i" && set /a "count+=1"
```

...but I need a way to compare this with a mass of files and display best matches which is a bit beyond my skill level. I need at least a good nudge to the right direction to get me started.

Here is an example of what I mean; this an example set of only 5 files to compare

```
From Dusk Till Dawn (1996) Robert Rodriguez [Horror, Action, Thriller, Crime] r6.9 1080p x265 AAC tt0116367.mkv
Full Metal Jacket (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0093058.mkv
Full Metal Jacket LOCKED AND LOADED Fanedit (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 720p x264 AC3 tt0093058.mkv
Desperado (1995) Robert Rodriguez [Thriller, Action, Crime] r6.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0112851.mkv
King of New York (1990) Abel Ferrara [Thriller, Crime] r6.5 1080p x265 AAC tt0099939.mp4
```

It should be able to process an entire directory tree of files. Resulting pairs should be listed in order of amount of matches:

```
10 words match
Full Metal Jacket (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0093058.mkv
Full Metal Jacket LOCKED AND LOADED Fanedit (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 720p x264 AC3 tt0093058.mkv

8 words match
From Dusk Till Dawn (1996) Robert Rodriguez [Horror, Action, Thriller, Crime] r6.9 1080p x265 AAC tt0116367.mkv
Desperado (1995) Robert Rodriguez [Thriller, Action, Crime] r6.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0112851.mkv

5 words match
From Dusk Till Dawn (1996) Robert Rodriguez [Horror, Action, Thriller, Crime] r6.9 1080p x265 AAC tt0116367.mkv
King of New York (1990) Abel Ferrara [Thriller, Crime] r6.5 1080p x265 AAC tt0099939.mp4

..and so on
```

I would like an adjustable number of required matches, for example don't display files with less than 6 matching words.

Comment: Do you want to compare _each word_ of `file1` vs _each word_ of `file2`? Or just compare first word vs. first word, second word vs. second word, etc...

Comment: Yes every word vs every word, regardless of order. separated by spaces

Comment: In order to write a working solution, I need you post a list of 8-10 file names and the output you want based on such a list. Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46870831/edit) the question, don't post any data here, in a comment. When you are ready, post a comment here and include @Aacini reference...

Comment: @Aacini question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. However, this problem is rather interesting to me, so I did an exception...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "minMatch=5"

rem Process all files in current directory
set /A "i=0, maxMatch=0"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /A-D /B') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "file[!i!]=%%~NXi"

   rem Compare this file vs. all files below it
   set "j=0"
   for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /A-D /B') do (
      set /A j+=1
      if !j! gtr !i! (

         rem Compare words, count match and store this pair of names
         set "n=0"
         for %%a in (%%~NXi) do for %%b in (%%~NXj) do (
            if /I "%%a" equ "%%b" set /A n+=1
         )
         if !n! geq %minMatch% (
            for %%n in (!n!) do set "match[%%n]=!match[%%n]! !i!+!j!"
            if !n! gtr !maxMatch! set /A maxMatch=n
         )

      )
   )

)

rem Show results
for /L %%n in (%maxMatch%,-1,%minMatch%) do if defined match[%%n] (
   echo %%n words match
   for %%m in (!match[%%n]!) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=+" %%i in ("%%m") do (
      echo !file[%%i]!
      echo !file[%%j]!
      echo/
   )
   echo/
)
```

Output example:

```
10 words match
Full Metal Jacket (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0093058.mkv
Full Metal Jacket LOCKED AND LOADED Fanedit (1987) Stanley Kubrick [Drama, War] r7.8 720p x264 AC3 tt0093058.mkv


7 words match
From Dusk Till Dawn (1996) Robert Rodriguez [Horror, Action, Thriller, Crime] r6.9 1080p x265 AAC tt0116367.mkv
Desperado (1995) Robert Rodriguez [Thriller, Action, Crime] r6.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0112851.mkv


5 words match
Desperado (1995) Robert Rodriguez [Thriller, Action, Crime] r6.8 1080p x265 AAC tt0112851.mkv
King of New York (1990) Abel Ferrara [Thriller, Crime] r6.5 1080p x265 AAC tt0099112851.mkv
```

You must realize that the number of operations involved in this program grow by a factor that depends on the number of files and the number of words in each file. If the number of files to process is large, this program may take too much time to complete...

Comment: Wow, that was way more complicated than I thought, sorry for asking while being way off. It works great so lots of thanks to you, sir! I'm gonna have to backwards engineer this so I can add a "words to ignore" list (like `1080p`) and possibly somehow make words like `[Action,` and `Action]` match. I can't ask any more of you unless you find that interesting also... Thanks again! Respect.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /a count=0
for %%i in (*) do set /a count+=1&CALL set "word%%count%%=%%i" 
SET wo
GOTO :EOF
```

I changed the filemask to `*` to suit my system.

`set /a` doesn't need quotes and ignores spaces. Use quotes to ensure trailing spaces are not included in the *string value* assigned.

Moving the `set count` before the assignment of the filename ensures numbering starting at `and ending at`count`.

`calling` the `set` parses the `set` so `%%i` will be replaced by it's value since it is a metavariable, and the other `%%`s are replaced by `%` since `%` escapes `%`, do the `set` is executed as 'set "word%count%=*value of %%i*" '

`set wo` shows all variables beginning `wo`

Comment: so how do I use this to make the actual comparison against the mass of files and declare results? I imagine I need a database file with each line being `D:\Path to\The File Name.ext|the|file|name` and then somehow compare how many words match in each filename. The full file path is needed for taking action or displaying top matching pairs.